# Root Partition Mounted Read-Only after Cloning

Tags: debian, mount

I have made a clone of a webserver system disk (Debian 8) using Clonezilla.  On booting I got this error:

```
No OS Found
```

All the files seemed fine and the problem turned out to be the MBR. The disk originally had a different distro on it. Although Clonezilla reported that it had copied the MBR over, the old MBR remained. I replaced the MBR using Debian Rescue and the system booted but the root partition mounts readonly. The `fstab` mount option is `errors=remount-ro`, `fsck` reports the partition as `Clean`.

This then causes `randon-seed` and `UTMP` failures.

Where should I be looking for the error?

Comment: No fsck errors, all mountpoints there? Can you add more technical details?

Comment: Have you tried `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda /` (assuming root is on /dev/sda...)

Comment: Already done that but it doesn't fix anything in the boot process, still mounts ro

Comment: What details would you like. @RuiFRibeiro

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/fstab`, it often contains UUID's. There's a program called `blkid` which allows you to retrieve those of partitions of the clone.

Comment: Clonezilla made a dogs dinner of the UUID translation, it translated the root uuid ok but left the swap uuid from the source drive, I corrected it manually after a 'remount-ro

Comment: I've never managed to get the UUID's working, perhaps because I always compile my own kernel.  I always replace them in my /etc/fstab by the old "/dev/sdx".   And I lived happily ever after.